# Delete old entries of the event-log with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to delete old entries of the event-log (where old means "older that X days") using PowerShell.
I found the [Clear-EventLog cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849789.aspx) but that

> Deletes all entries from specified event logs on the local or remote computers.

I have found a lot of scripts that use this cmdlet to delete ALL entries -
but is there a way to select only some [old] entries of the event-log and delete only those?

Comment: No can do. This behaviour is by design.
http://serverfault.com/questions/8339/how-can-i-remove-specific-events-from-the-event-log-in-windows-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

As James said, you can't. But if you want to keep a date range part of your log, it's not clean but here's a workaround:

1. you backup the messages you want to keep with the 'wevutil' utility (http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc732848%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
   Something like that:

   $LogName="Application"
   $DateStart=(Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)
   $DateEnd=Get-Date
   $EvtFile="$ComputerName" + "-EventLogExport-" + "$LogName" + ".evtx"
   function Get-Milliseconds ($EventsDate) {
       $EventsTimeSpan=New-TimeSpan -Start $EventsDate -End (Get-Date)
       [math]::Round($EventsTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds)
   } # end function
   $EventsDateStart=Get-Milliseconds(Get-Date $DateStart)
   $EventsDateEnd=Get-Milliseconds(Get-Date $DateEnd)

   wevtutil epl $LogName $EvtFile /q:"*[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime)>=$EventsDateEnd] and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= $EventsDateStart]]]"
2. Use the Clear-EventLog cmdlet to empty your event log.

Answer (score 0):

[I found a one-liner](http://kristofmattei.be/2011/06/14/clear-all-event-logs-on-windows-using-powershell/) to remove ALL entries from ALL eventlogs
e.g.

```
wevtutil el | Foreach-Object {Write-Host "Clearing $_"; wevtutil cl "$_"}
```

Personally I either set a limit on eventlog size

```
limit-eventLog -logname Security -MaximumSize 64KB
```

or do a monthly export and delete after export.