# Delete old entries of the event-log with PowerShell or CMD? (Not all of them | With period of time condition)

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, event-log

Please take a look at these two threads :

[how-to-clear-eventlog-with-powershell-or-wevtutil](https://deploywindows.com/2015/10/22/how-to-clear-eventlog-with-powershell-or-wevtutil/)

[delete-old-entries-of-the-event-log-with-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067386/delete-old-entries-of-the-event-log-with-powershell)

Some days ago some body stole my password of wi-fi and connected to it.
After connect he hacked my windows 7 pc through home network.
Something is so strange for me.
After hack he deleted all wi-fi logs for two moths ago.
I never do that because i even did n't know there is a wi-fi log in my pc.
[Check here for wi-fi logs & it's location](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_history_view.html)
How is that possible because people say you can't delete event logs in period of time by command.
Just tell me how could he do that?
Does he have GUI access to my pc?
I am so confused because of this action?

Comment: First: Disconnect from the internet. Second: Log out of all online accounts. Third: Make a backup of your drive. Fourth: Scan your computer for malware and viruses.

Comment: That rootkit is undetectable. Owner mailed me that his payload is changing it's signature repeatedly. I did scan my pc with Norton - Eset Internet Security - MalwareBytes.
Norton was in boot.
The others were already installed on my machine = updated + latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost anything is possible if you have administrator rights on a machine

There is no built-in function to delete only certain logs, but one example way to do this is simply export all logs except the ones you want, then replace the original log file with your filtered log. The built-in `wevtutil` can do this pretty easily:

```
# filter out events on 2022-05-11
# export to test.evtx
wevtutil epl Application test.evtx "/q:*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime<='2022-05-13T23:00:00.000Z' and @SystemTime>='2022-05-10T04:00:00.999Z']]]"
```

---

That aside - Windows 7 stopped receiving security patches in January of 2020, so consider upgrading your operating system for the future.

If you think that person could still have access to your computer, then your best action is to is to wipe it and start over. A computer repair service should be able to help you do this and keep your important files.

Comment: Thanks for your command. But it tells : "Failed to export log Application. The specified query is invalid."

Comment: @SilverLight It's just an example. I've fixed the syntax to something usable